# Java compile not working... installed JDK and it has worked before

Tags: java, javac

OK... This is kind of odd. So, yesterday, on my new computer, I installed the latest JDK 8 for Windows 7. I input it to environmental variables, I did everything correctly, and I know it for sure because it worked yesterday. I compiled multiple .javas. But now today, I use the javac on any .java, and the CMD prompt just goes back to "C:\Users\Home Computer>"
I've restarted, hours of research, but this problem seems new. Even uninstalled and reinstalled JDK. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

[Command Prompt Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liJQ1.png)

Comment: There must be a problem in your environment variables. Go and check in the environment variables whether the JDK directory is in the PATH variable in the environment variables.http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7

Comment: Are you setting the destination folder for your class files? Maybe they are being compiled but placed somewhere you didn't expect or look

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @PaulGuiheen It doesn't give any feedback whatsoever. it just goes back like i didnt even type a command

Comment: @DROY I'm not getting an error. In fact, that is the problem! I'm not getting any feedback whatsoever via command prompt. other commands will work, like >java program, but with javac it just stops for a while and then goes back to the directory like i didn't even type anything.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha Aha! I reset my path, and I got the compile error notes. Sadly, it did not compile (make any .class files), yet that's one step closer! It still won't show the compiling, but it shows errors in the code.

Comment: Thats up to you. Debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open CMD, type in "java -version", press Enter & show us what you got there. Does it look like:

> C:\Users\W>java -version
>
> java version "1.8.0_66"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
>
> C:\Users\W>

You can debug it step by step following the official guide of Oracle or external document:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html
https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_Howto.html

Comment: Yes, it almost says exactly that, except for the version is 1.8.0_77 and build is b03.

Comment: Could you give us the full step you made & the result of each of them?

Comment: Do you want the code? If it helps, I posted a link to a screenshot i got of the command prompt

Comment: Yeah, I need your source code. Maybe your program ran well but it just didn't print anything to the console.

Comment: Ok... the code is too long to put in the box by 1244 characters... It may help to say that it isn't just one .java file, it's all of them. none of them will compile, and some were the same when they worked as when they stopped working.

Comment: Can you run a helloworld app by using javac? Have you tried to run your app by using Eclipse IDE or in another PC with javac? If none of them works, you'll need to submit your code (via Dropbox or OneDrive...) & we'll try to help you debug them.